# defining functions on a chosen range, Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Is there a way to define a function on a specific domain in mathematica? I need this because I want to invert a function which is only monotonic on a specific domain.
For example:

```
 f[x_]:=x^2
 g[x_]:=InverseFunction[f][x]
```

will give me $Failed report. This is because the parabolic function is only monotonic on x>0 or x<0. Is there a way to specify this when defining the function?

Thanks!

Comment: I do not get `$Failed` but rather a warning "InverseFunction::ifun: Inverse functions are being used. Values may be lost for multivalued inverses. >>" *and* an output.  Which version are you using?

Comment: It is Mathematica 9, and now that I test it, it gives me the same warning as you mentioned. I guess when I did it, the mathematica was already filled with various scripts, so the $Failed warning could come from anything in the context. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for your example.

```
f[x_ /; x != 0] := x^2 
g[y_] := InverseFunction[f][y]
Plot[g[z], {z, -2, 2}]
```

[image]